# How can I use Java Stream to find the average of all values that share a key?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm having a lot of trouble with trying to average the values of a map in java. My method takes in a text file and sees the average length of each word starting with a certain letter (case insensitive and goes through all words in the text file.

For example, let's say I have a text file that contains the following::

```
"Apple arrow are very common Because bees behave Cant you come home"
```

My method currently returns:

```
{A=5, a=8, B=7, b=10, c=10, C=5, v=4, h=4, y=3}
```

Because it is looking at the letters and finding the average length of the word, but it is still case sensitive.

It should return:

```
{A=5, a=8, B=7, b=10, c=10, C=5, v=4, h=4, y=3}

{a=4.3, b=5.5, c=5.0, v=4.0, h=4.0, y=3}
```

This is what I have so far.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> findAverageLength(String filename) {
    
     Map<String, Integer> wordcount = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
       
        try 
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (in.hasNext()) 
            {
                wordList.add(in.next());
            }

            wordcount = wordList.stream().collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(w->w.substring(0,1), w -> w.length(), Integer::sum));
            System.out.println(wordcount);
            
        }
        
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File: " + filename + " not found");
        }
                    
  return wordcount; 
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are almost there.

You could try the following.

- We group by the first character of the word, converted to lowercase. This lets us collect into a `Map<Character, …>`, where the key is the first letter of each word. A typical map entry would then look like

  ```
  a = [ Apple, arrow, are ]
  ```
- Then, the average of each group of word lengths is calculated, using the `averagingDouble` method. A typical map entry would then look like

  ```
  a = 4.33333333
  ```

Here is the code:

```java
// groupingBy and averagingDouble are static imports from
// java.util.stream.Collectors
Map<Character, Double> map = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
    .collect(groupingBy(word -> Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0)),
        averagingDouble(String::length)));
```

---

Note that, for brevity, I left out additional things like `null` checks, empty strings and `Locale`s.

Also note that this code was heavily improved responding to the comments of Olivier Grégoire and Holger below.

Comment: It's an excellent answer, but it'd be better if the lowercase would be applied on the key only: `groupingBy(word -> word.substring(0,1).toLowerCase(), ...)`. This way, if you have very very long words, they're not entirely lowercased, but only the part needed: the first letter.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Good point, I'll incorporate that into the answer.

Comment: I'm quite unfamiliar with using averagingDouble and my code is showing me an error that says the method does not exist.

Comment: @Holger I do have it but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: And while at it, how about using the mapFactory parameter of groupingBy to get a nicely ordered result? `wordList.stream().collect(groupingBy(i -> i.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(), () -> new TreeMap<>(), averagingDouble(i -> i.length())));`

Comment: @timtommy it’s hard to say what’s going wrong, without further context. The [method is there](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction)), since Java 8. Well, there are too many `)` at the end in this answer. When I remove one `)`, it works for me. Compare with https://ideone.com/7Rzcuw and see if you can spot other difference to your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with the following:

```
String str = "Apple arrow are very common Because bees behave Cant you come home";
Map<String, Double> map = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> String.valueOf(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(0))),
                    Collectors.averagingDouble(String::length)));
```

The `split` method will split the string into an array of strings using the delimiter " ". Then, you want to group by the average of the string length. Hence, the use the of `Collectors.groupingBy` method and the downstream parameter `Collectors.averagingDouble(String::length)`. Finally, given the constraints that you have described we need to group by lower case (or up case) of the first char in the String (*i.e.,* `Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(0)))`).

and then print the map:

```
 map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you do not need to keep the map structure you can do it in one go:

```
Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> String.valueOf(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(0))), Collectors.averagingDouble(String::length)))
      .entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the first letter, which you obtain using `substring`, to the same case. Upper or lower, doesn't matter.

```
w.substring(0,1).toLowercase()
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a case-insensitive map, but you haven't used it. Try `Collectors.toMap(w->w.substring(0,1), w -> w.length(), Integer::sum, () -> new TreeMap<String, Integer>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))`, or just `Collectors.toMap(w->w.toUpperCase().substring(0,1), w -> w.length(), Integer::sum)`